# implementation details of EvoSuite

Tags: algorithm, genetic, evosuite

I am using EvoSuite and everything is fine in generating the test suites. 
But I need to know how it works. I know it uses GAs, but I am interested in the implementation details.
1. Are ASTs (abstract syntax trees) used in order to implement the GA?
2. having the bytecode; what are the next steps performed in order to get all the necessary information to generate the test suites?

Is there any reference concerning these issues?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

EvoSuite is released as open source at: https://github.com/EvoSuite/evosuite

So you can look directly at its code to see its details. For higher level documentation, you can see http://www.evosuite.org/publications/

Comment: Thank You! I have read several papers regarding EvoSuite. I have tried to understand the code too. I know Java quite well from the books, but since I have not worked with such a big project as EvoSuite, can You please suggest me which are the classes to start studying the project in order to understand the rest of them? What advanced features of Java should I learn to comprehend this project (e.g. Reflection)? Maybe these questions are not professional, but I am having difficulties in understanding the code. Thank You